# How to read text file from mainframe through .net application?

Tags: .net, mainframe

Some plain text file is stored in mainframe server, i have to read the file and populate the data to SQL database.
Any ideas please suggest.

Comment: What libraries are you using to connect to the mainframe?

Comment: @user472269 : you need to provide a whole lot more information, and if possible some sample code to show what you've tried up til now. Your question is very likely going to be closed if you don't provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a member in a PDS FTP the member down to the PC, parse it, and insert the data into the SQL Server database. With out more information that's the best idea I can give you.

Answer (score 2):

I'll 2nd Jared's suggestion but add that if you FTP the data make sure you specify the FTP options ASCII and CRLF (for plain text).  This will translate the EBCDIC characterset to ASCII and append the CRLF record delimiter to each record in the text file.